# Error in Ruby logs -> ActiveRecord::RecordNotFound (Couldn't find Plan with 'id'=1):

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, git, heroku, activerecord

I a having issues with Heroku, I have a project which is working fine on C9 but when I push to Heroku it gives me the following error in the logs

> ActiveRecord::RecordNotFound (Couldn't find Plan with 'id'=1)

resulting in following error on my homepage ->

> The page you were looking for doesn't exist.

You may have mistyped the address or the page may have moved.

**home.html.erb**

```
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-6">
        <div class="well">
            <h3 class="text-center">Basic membership</H3>
            <h4>Hier inschrijven voor alle leden van het gezin.</h4>
            <br />
            <%= link_to "Sign up free", new_user_registration_path(plan: Plan.find(1).id), class: 'btn btn-primary btn-lg btn-block' %>
        </div>
    </div>

     <div class="col-md-6">
         <div class="well">
             <h3 class="text-center">Premium membership</h3>
             <h4>Niet gebruiken dit is een test object.</h4>
             <br />
             <%= link_to "Sign up for premium plan", new_user_registration_path(plan: Plan.find(2).id), class: 'btn btn-success btn-lg btn-block' %>
         </div>
```

**pages_controller**

```
class PagesController < ApplicationController
    def home
        @basic_plan = Plan.find(1)
        @pro_plan = Plan.find(2)
    end

    def about
    end
end
```

I am using devise gem for storing the users as can be seen in the following snippet

```
Rails.application.routes.draw do
  devise_for :users
  resources :contacts
  get '/about' => 'pages#about'
  root 'pages#home'
```

everything is backed up to GitHub from master branch and after that pushed to Heroku via master again... It can't find the solution, help would be welcome :)

Comment: C9 database would have data in `plans` table which is not available to Heroku. You need to create these data in your production db.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your Plan table may be empty or plan created with any other id, you should export DB from `C9` and import it to `Heroku`

and as an extra note you can't depend on ids, `id` column is auto increment and if you created some planes and deleted after, then new created plans may start with id=5 as an example, and if you even force the id you still shouldn't do that.

My suggestion if you have a plan name or any other uniq column for Plan table use it:

```
Plan.find_by_name('plan_name').id
```

or even use:  (in case you are sure you free plan is always created first)

```
Plan.order('id').first
Plan.order('id').last
```

Answer (score 3):

> ActiveRecord::RecordNotFound (Couldn't find Plan with 'id'=1)

Clearly, you don't have `Plan` with `id = 1` in your database

and finding record with hardcoded id is bad practice:

```
new_user_registration_path(plan: Plan.find(1).id)
```

You can do the same with

```
new_user_registration_path(plan: 1)
```

`Plan.find(1).id` will return you `1` only

**OR**

```
new_user_registration_path(plan: Plan.find_by_name('Premium').try(:id))
```

**NOTE:** Also make sure you have created `Plans` on your production db

Comment: yeah, I assigned variables to the plan, I just tried it through hardcoding to see of that was a part of the error that did not seem the problem will change it back to the variable name :). Thx for the input. And I indeed do not have my db properly migrated to Heroku pretty new to this stuff...

Answer (score 2):

Check your heroku database. Most likely, your plans table is empty.

Comment: Ok, this seems to be the case I used "heroku run rails console" and checked Plan.all came up empty don't really understand how this is though I migrated my database several times, using "heroku run rake db:migrate" I guess I am using the wrong command?

Comment: rake db:migrate only creates and updates your db schema. To load default data, you'll want to use seeds.rb and run rake db:seed.

Comment: Thx for the help now atleast I know what my fault was :)

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem, but being so new to ruby/rails, I had no idea how to add the plan to Heroku db..As mentioned above by everyone :P After a lot of time clicking through stackoverflow, I finally figured it out.  So Simple!

For any other noobs like me, here is how you create a table in Heroku. (plans table in this situation)

```
$ Heroku run rails console
> Plan.create(name: 'basic', price: 0)
> Plan.create(name: 'pro', price: 10)
```

Then check if it works:

```
> Plan.all
```

This should list your plans and their corresponding 'id'.

Hope this helps!